# Angular 1.6 ui-router and ng-include in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I am developing an Angular 1.6 app and using Angular UI-Router.

In my config.router.js file I have a state:

```
$stateProvider.state('myapp.edit', {
                    url: '/edit/:id',
                    templateUrl: 'views/actions/edit.html',
                    controller: ['$http','$rootScope',function( $http, $rootScope){
                            $rootScope.displaySideBar = true;

                        }]

                    });
```

In the application layout file `layout.html` file I have included navbar `navbar.html` file using `data-ng-include`

```
<div data-ng-include=" 'views/partials/navbar.html' "></div>
```

But when I run the application and check the browser console its checking for `myapp/edit/views/partials/navbar.html` instead of `myapp/views/partials/navbar.html` .
The state url is getting prepended while performing ng-include and ending up in 404 only in IE. In other browsers its working fine.

Can somebody kindly help me on this.

Comment: What is the url for myapp state?

Comment: It is '/myapp' .